# Material Dashboard React select input does not show the arrow icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-forms, select-options

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPMbd.png)
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCBFi.png)

Is there any reason to view the select like this. Arrow icon not visible. I'm using the "@mui/material": "^5.8.6". Please help me on this

```
<Box sx={{ width: "auto" }}>
    <FormControl fullWidth>
        <TextField
            select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
            id="demo-simple-select"
            value={gender}
            label="Gender"
            onChange={(e) => setGender(e.target.value)}
        >
            <MenuItem value="Male">Male</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="Female">Female</MenuItem>
        </TextField>
    </FormControl>
</Box>
```

Comment: Seems some styles that you have added to to wrapper elements have caused this issue. See it's working here => https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-banzai-kveib3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The problem is arrow icon is not visible in my code. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: Create a codesandbox recreating your issue so someone can help you.  This is just CSS issue. You can use browser inspect tools and check what are the applied styles to drop down element

Comment: I'm using https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard-react template. I want to add a select box to a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [Material Dashboard 2 React](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard-react) does not support a select input by looking into their [docs](https://www.creative-tim.com/learning-lab/react/input/material-dashboard/).

But under the hood, they use `TextField` from `@mui/material` along with `@mui/material/styles` and `TextField` can be a select input. See the code in `MDInputRoot.js`.

1. Replace your code for select input with the following theme native component except the `MenuItem` which has to be imported from `@mui/material`:

```
<MDBox mb={2}>
  <MDInput
    size="large"
    select
    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
    id="demo-simple-select"
    //value={gender}
    label="Gender"
    InputProps={{
      classes: { root: "select-input-styles" },
    }}
    fullWidth
  >
    <MenuItem value="Male">Male</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="Female">Female</MenuItem>
  </MDInput>
</MDBox>
```

We have set a new root-level CSS class for the input element by providing class using the `InputProps`.

2. Then create a new CSS file named `inputCustomStyles.css` inside `src/components/MDInput` directory.

```
.select-input-styles {
    padding: 12px 0;
}

.select-input-styles svg {
    display: block;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    top: calc(50% - 1em);
}
```

`padding` has been changed to fix the input height issue you have got and `svg` display set to block to make the arrow icon visible.

3. Now import the styles in the top of `MDRootInput.js` file:

```
...
...
import "./inputCustomStyles.css";
```

I have checked the changes in the `src/layouts/authentication/sign-in/index.js` file and it look like below:

[image]

Comment: @Yasas Ekanayaka, check this out!!